# Dark blue bars in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

For my cv i am using the following template: [moderncv](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter-2015-version/sttkgjcysttn)

The template contains a command with which the colors of the bars can be set

```
\moderncvcolor{black} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
```

For my application I would like to use a dark blue color like in the picture below

[image]

Does someone of you know how this can be done?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 


\begin{document}
\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours} 



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the example, but this one doesn't quite compile without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a new colour specifically for the rule, and then redefine the `\section` command. Here's how:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{5,40,135}% dark blue
\makeatletter
\@initializelength{\baseletterheight}
\settoheight{\baseletterheight}{\sectionstyle{o}}
\setlength{\baseletterheight}{\baseletterheight-0.95ex}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{\strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{\color{color4}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.95ex}}}{\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours} 



\end{document}
```

[image]